# Which sentence is gramatically and sounds right?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-participles

I'm sorry for the mistakes that I did.

or

I'm sorry for the mistakes that I have done.

Which sentence is grammatically and sounds right?

Comment: You meant to say _grammatical_ not _grammatically_ as you needed an adjective not an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

We **make** mistakes.

*I'm sorry for the mistakes that I made.*

*I'm sorry for the mistakes that I have made.*

Both of the above are grammatically correct. They just use different verb tenses, e.g.

*I saw it.*

*I have seen it.*

*I made mistakes.*

*I have made made mistakes.*

All are correct.